# addClass should only apply to the next IMG

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I hope somebody can help me.
how can I make addClass applies only to the next img and not to all following?
edit: the "addClass" should always apply to the next following IMG so that you can click through all images one after an other - like a gallery

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    if($("#gallery li").next("#gallery li").length != 0) {
        $("#gallery li").children("img").removeClass('toppicture');
        $("#gallery li").next("#gallery li").children("img").addClass('toppicture');
    }
    else {
        $(this).children("img").removeClass('toppicture');
        $("#gallery li:first-child").children("img").addClass('toppicture');
    }
});
```

the ul with the id "gallery" looks like this :

```
<li>
    <img class="toppicture" src="images/w1.jpg" title="Title #0"/>
</li>
<li>
    <img  src="images/w2.jpg" title="Title #1"/>
</li>
<li>
    <img  src="images/w3.jpg" title="Title #2"/>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
$("#next").click(function(){
                if($("#gallery li").next("#gallery li").length != 0) {
                    var obj = $(".toppicture").parent("li").next().children("img");
                    $("#gallery li").children("img").removeClass('toppicture');
                    $(obj).addClass('toppicture');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).children("img").removeClass('toppicture');
                    $("#gallery li:first-child").children("img").addClass('toppicture');
                }
            });
```

source : http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! if I do it like this ("img:first") it applies to the next but then it doesn't goes further.

Comment: NP! Sorry, i thought that is what you wanted : how can I make addClass applies only to the next img and not to all following? Would it be possible to explain in more details what should happen?

Comment: the "addClass" should always apply to the next following IMG so that you can click through all images one after an other - like a gallery

Comment: I have edited my answer above, please see if that helps. What i've done is create the object of the next image, then remove the toppicture class cross board, then add it only to the object.

Comment: amazing stuff! works fine! the only thing now is, that it doesn't jump back to the first child (image) if I am at the end of the image list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    //find the li with the class
    var liTop = $("#gallery li.toppicture");
    //if it has another element remove the class from itself and add it to the next 
    if(liTop.next().length !== 0) {
        liTop.removeClass('toppicture');
        liTop.next().addClass('toppicture');
    }
    else {
        $(this).children("img").removeClass('toppicture');
        $("#gallery li:first-child").children("img").addClass('toppicture');
    }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt't work for me. it just works if I remove ".toppicture" in the second line so it is: $("#gallery li"). but the it also applies to every image in the list. thanks anyway!!